# Can´t Sync Nitrous.io Desktop

Tags: nitrousio

I'm teaching a php course at a community college and I wanted to use Nitrous as an environment but I can't sync my files with the desktop application, I guess it's a network firewall block (already turned off the OS firewall, windows xp btw), any info on what port should I ask the admin to whitelist?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is a firewall problem. I have the same issue here. In the file system, my box shows in the Nitrous folder, so there is at least some communication otherwise how could it know the name of the box. But in the folder with the boxname, nothing else shows but the .unison file, which it should have ignored according to docs.
I am missing all of the files that should be there.
In my Nitrous desktop app, file sync is "ON" and I specifically allowed the program in the firewall settings. However, nothing in my boxfolder syncs.
This could be the same problem you are having.

Comment: As it turns out, everything to be synchronized needs to be in the ~/workspace folder or else sync will fail.